# Prompting for user input in Postman

Tags: javascript, postman, web-api-testing

How can I ask for user input in Postman scripts?

I am using Postman 4.8.3, Chrome app.
I have used environment variables in most cases, but for a particular case I need user to provide input for each run (I am not running collection. Instead want to make the individual Postman call more interactive as I am dealing with some management APIs). I want to insert a code like:

```
prompt("Enter resource id","#id");
```

in the Pre-request Script. 
However, when I do so, Postman ignores it and moves ahead.
Please help.

Comment: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/285

This is not allowed by Chrome apps. So what you are attempting is not possible.

Answer (score 6):

As stated by another, Chrome extensions reportedly doesn't allow prompt. BUT there are now native versions of Postman (Windows, Mac, Linux) and according to this  [nearly four year old feature request](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/285), they are working on this and will post to the request when the ability to prompt is in the Canary version.

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe this feature is available as of today too. Unless you can use the Path variables or query parameters

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).